# How to change the order of tuple's items in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, tuples

I am really stuck with this. I have to create two functions. The first one takes a string as an argument then creates and returns a tuple. The string has the following format: fisrt_name, last_name, salary. However, I must change the order to salary, first_name, last_name. Any ideas on how to do it? This is what I have so far:

```
def function_one(person_string):
    first_name, last_name, salary=person_string.split('')
    return salary, first_name, last_name

def function_two(person_tuple):
    string_person = ' '.join(person_tuple)
    return string_person

path_to_file = 'person.txt'
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as file
    content = file.read()

print(content)

with open(path_to_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        tuple_person = string_to_tuple(line)
        print(tuple_person)
```

Comment: What isn't working?

Comment: Basically it just won't change the order. It remains with the initial one which is: first_name, last_name, salary.

Comment: You need to show how you're calling these functions, they do exactly what you're trying to get them to do so these arent the issue

Comment: @Sayse I call them from a file. I will update the code part.

Comment: `string.split('')` should be `string.split()`. Splitting on the empty string isn't valid in Python. In any event -- you need to be informative and tell us *how* the function isn't working.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right. I made some edits on the code part. The output is basically the same as the input. For example, the file contains information in the following order: first_name, last_name, salary, and must give the output in a different order: salary, first_name, last_name. However, the order doesn't change, it stays the same as the input.

Comment: @girijesh96 thats more swapping 2 items in a list than swapping items in a tuple

Comment: @HristoGeorgiev you still can't see how you're calling these functions.

Comment: You aren't even calling your `function_one` on the input -- so why do you expect it to be applied to the input? What is `string_to_tuple`?

Comment: @Annihil8 That's my whole code. I am surely doing something wrong...

Comment: That can't possibly be your whole code if you aren't getting a run-time error (rather than, as you report, unexpected output). Your code is calling a function which isn't defined anywhere in the posted code.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it like this

```
def function_one(person_string):
    data = person_string.split(' ')
    return (data[2], data[0], data[1])

def function_two(person_tuple):
    string_person = ' '.join(person_tuple)
    return string_person
Jhon = 'Jhon Smith 100000'
string = function_one(Jhon)
out    = function_two(string)
print(string, out)

out:('100000', 'Jhon', 'Smith') 100000 Jhon Smith
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do something like this?

```
peoples = ["jordan lee 21", "megan bob 35",]
peoples_2 = []

for people in peoples:
    first_name, last_name, salary = people.split()
    peoples_2.append('{} {} {}'.format(salary, first_name, last_name))

print(peoples_2)
```

And if you really need it to be  a tuple or list just cast it

```
tuple(peoples_2)
```

Just replace the hardcoded peoples list with the previous way you were getting the list.